# Provide C#'s namespace from IronPython

Tags: mono, ironpython

I want to write Tomboy add-on using IronPython and I'm stuck and very beginning -- I need to provide C#'s namespace.

I mean, here's howto in writing Tomboy add-on's http://live.gnome.org/Tomboy/HowToCreateAddins

> Let's start with creating the plugin
>   file called InsertDateTime.cs with the
>   following content:
>
> ```
> using Tomboy;
>
> namespace Tomboy.InsertDateTime
> {
>         public class InsertDateTimeAddin : NoteAddin
>         {
>                 public override void Initialize ()
>                 {
>                 }
>
>                 public override void Shutdown ()
>                 {
>                 }
>
>                 public override void OnNoteOpened ()
>                 {
>                 }
>         }
> }
> ```

Can I do that with IronPython? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "provide C#'s namespace"? Could you clarify further?

Comment: Cameron, I've updated the topic. Hope that helps)

Answer (score 0):

From Python you can import the clr module and then call clr.AddReference('AssemblyName') where assembly name is a partial or full assembly name - maybe in your case it's Tomboy, it's whatever you'd compile against with C#.  Then you can do "import Tomboy" or "from Tomboy import NoteAddin".

If you're hosting IronPython via the hosting APIs you can instead do scriptRuntime.LoadAssembly(typeof(NoetAddin).Assembly); so that you don't have to do it in Python.  That can be particularly useful to avoid various loader context issues depending on how the assembly gets loaded.

Comment: Ummm... But I didn't really get how that helps to provide a namespace) I mean, I need to build an assembly with namespace called Tomboy.InsertDateTime from IronPython. How can I do that? (what you wrote is how to use existing namespace from IronPython, but I need to do that in different way ))

Comment: Oh, I see...  IronPython 1.x's CodeDom provider supported doing this for ASP.NET but IronPython 2.x doesn't - this doesn't really make much sense for Python.